# Put "List of Objects" in KrollDict with Titanium Android Module Development

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I have a custom class declared in the module source code.

```
public class Friend{
    public String name;
    public List<String> phoneNumbers;
    public List<String> emailAddresses;

    public Friend(String name, List<String>emailAddresses, 
    List<String>phoneNumbers){
        this.name = name;
        this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

I declared an Android Method in the Module

```
@Kroll.method
protected synchronized void getListOfObjects(){
    List<String> emailAddresses = Arrays.asList("email1@yahoo.com", "email2@yahoo.com", "email3@yahoo.com");
    List<String> phoneNumbers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    List<Friend> friendList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    friendList.add(new Friend("test1", emailAddresses, phoneNumbers));
    friendList.add(new Friend("test2", emailAddresses, phoneNumbers));
    friendList.add(new Friend("test3", emailAddresses, phoneNumbers));


    KrollDict kd = new KrollDict();
    kd.put("friendList", friendList);
    if (hasListeners("onShow")) {
        fireEvent("onShow", kd);
    }
}
```

Upon Calling the getListOfOjects method in the Titanium App

```
module.getListOfObjects();
module.addEventListener('onShow', function(e){
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e.friendList));
});
```

I cant seem to retrieve the friendList object.

The EXPECTED RESULT that I wanted to achieve would be like this

```
[
    {test1, ["email1@yahoo.com", "email2@yahoo.com", "email3@yahoo.com"], ["1", "2", "3"]},
    {test2, ["email1@yahoo.com", "email2@yahoo.com", "email3@yahoo.com"], ["1", "2", "3"]},
    {test3, ["email1@yahoo.com", "email2@yahoo.com", "email3@yahoo.com"], ["1", "2", "3"]}
]
```

The question is, **HOW TO ACHIEVE THE EXPECTED RESULT BASED ON THE SAMPLE CODES ABOVE?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the List object into JSON string using GSON and assign the result string to the KrollDict property

```
KrollDict kd = new KrollDict();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String friendListStr = gson.toJson(friendList);
kd.put("friendList", friendListStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to return an object array like this:

```java
KrollDict kd = new KrollDict();
Object[] obj = new Object[friendList.size()];

for (int i=0; i< friendList.size(); ++i){
    KrollDict model = new KrollDict();
    model.put("name", friendList.get(i).name);
    // ...
    obj[i] = model;
}

kd.put("list", obj);
fireEvent("onShow", kd);
```

That way you'll have an array in your event and don't need to convert that string into json later on.

If you want to use a JSON you can use `TiConvert` with `toJSON`, `toJSONArray` or `toJSONString` depending on your parameter. No need for Gson.